# What does rational expression mean?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, rational-numbers, rational-functions

I need further understanding on rational expressions. I link here to the original website [ClickMe](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c626.html)

[image: Rational expression]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to reformat your question. There are many parts of your question that are unclear and incomprehensible.

Comment: At which level of tuition did you run into this concept?

Comment: You don't give the definition your first sentence talks about.  And your second sentence does not have a verb. I agree with irregardless: your question is unclear and incomprehensible.

Comment: Can you please guide me further?

Comment: @kimchi lover ...this question is about mathematics and not English grammar. What if person's first language is not English? So here you will not receive help?

Comment: I would be glad to try to help you with your mathematics question if I could understand it.

Comment: @UbiBhatt Please type out the definition that you are using. That will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Théophile did already, thanks :)

Comment: @kimchilover I have added the link of the image please check!! :)

Comment: The definition that you linked is far to imprecise to infer a unique meaning. Please give some further context. Where did you find that definition?

Comment: @BillDubuque I have attached the link of the websites. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rational expression involving a set of numbers (or variables, or other things you can add and multiply) is an expression using those numbers and the operations addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Since integral powers are just repeated multiplications, they are allowed in rational expressions.

So
$$
\frac{3x^2}{x-1}
$$
is a rational expression in $x$.

Sometimes an expression that does not look like a rational expression has a (more or less) equivalent form that is. So
$$
\sqrt[3]{(x  - 3)^3}
$$
isn't a rational expression, but it's equal to the rational expression $x-3$.

I think that may explain the "reducible" and "irreducible" examples in the definition, but I don't like that distinction.

With square roots (as in the example you cite) you have to be careful about positive square roots when necessary - but that's a whole other kind of question.
The fact that $|x|$ is either $x$ or $-x$ does *not* make $|x|$ a rational expression, since you need the full logic "if $x \ge 0$ then $|x| = x$ else ..." to calculate it, and the "if" part isn't a rational expression.

Comment: can you tell why Square root of x is not a rational expression? I am confuse on that part.

Comment: @UbiBhatt See [Rational Function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function)

Comment: Square root is not a rational operation since you can't get it by combining additiions, subtractions, multiplications and divisions.

Comment: @EthanBolker I guess I bit clear now. I was confused with rational exponent and rational expression. I thought why rational exponents are not allowed in rational expression. Thanks, now I understood!!

Comment: @UbiBhatt Glad to help. You can accept the answer (check mark), and upvote it (up arrow) if you wish.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry, but I learned that you need 15 reputation to upvote. Between, if I can, I would like to check mark it. Totally new to this site, so how to do it? Thanks!!

Comment: @EthanBolker I have check marked it :) thanks!! (I am at only 6 reputation so can't upvote it)

Comment: The last example is misleading since $\sqrt{(x-3)^2}=|x-3|$. Perhaps an example with cube root would be better?

Comment: @Théophile Edited thanks.

Comment: @Theophile why you think it is misleading because when you remove square root of x^2 = |x| which is -x or +x.  Both are rational expressions.

Comment: See my edit in response to your question for @Théophile .